# /dev/null doesn't seem to be working in docker container

Tags: travis-ci

I am running some automates tests in Travis-CI and I'm having troubles understanding some strange behaviour. The problem is the following: There is one long command that uses lots of redirections:

`bamtofastq filename=input.bam T=temp.fq-sort F=>(bgzip -c /dev/stdin > matched_1.fq.gz) F2=>(bgzip -c /dev/stdin > matched_2.fq.gz) S=/dev/null O=/dev/null O2=/dev/null collate=1 colsbs=1048576`

the arguments `S`, `O` and `O2` are redirecting outputs to `/dev/null`, so nothing should be shown in stdout. If I run the tests locally everything works, however, when I run the tests in Travis, for some reason is redirecting those outputs to stdout. Please have a look at this build log to see what I mean: https://travis-ci.org/guillermo-carrasco/bcbio-nextgen/builds/81020672

I really have no clue about what is happening. I've even fired a small test doing an `ls > /dev/null` inside the container to see if there was a problem with `/dev/null` in the docker image, but it worked as expected.

Any ideas on what to consider would be really appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Run the command in the container?

Comment: yes, the command is ran in the container

Comment: Humm... is it possible for you to `docker-build` a container with just that command and try to reproduce that behavior? Let's try to isolate this insolent bug! :)

Comment: Well, I can try to do that locally, but the problem is that it does work as expected locally. I wouldn't like to throw random tests at Travis. On the other hand I don't see other way if the problem is there. I'll try to isolate the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, apparently it was just a matter of adding `--privileged` to the docker command. This makes the container to be able to use the host devices, i.e `/dev/null`. Thanks a lot to Travis-CI for the suggestion: https://twitter.com/travisci/status/646027217147961344